# PHP in_array and MYSQL

Tags: php, arrays

I need to compare to different mysql arrays with in_array. It works like this:

```
    if (in_array('cedcfecaffbecac', $sword)){
    echo "tst";
     }
```

But I need to do this

```
     if (in_array($sword2, $sword1)){
    echo "tst";
     }
```

I need to determine if for example, one entry in $sword1 equals an entry in $swords2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array` doesn't compare arrays, it checks if a value exists in an array.

If you wish to compare 2 arrays you can use `array_diff`:

```
if (!count(array_diff($sword1, $sword2))) {
  echo "arrays are identical";
}
```

Comment: What if I just want to see if one array member equals at least one member in another array?

Comment: For example, is there an entry in $sword1 that equals an entry in $swords2

Comment: In this case you can use `array_intersect($sword1, $sword2)`.

Comment: Solved. Thanks. array_intersect

Answer (score 1):

Here [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) will do the trick

```
if(!empty($result = array_intersect($array1, $array2)))
{
  var_dump($result);//dumps matched values stored in $result array
}
```

Comment: thanks. would it be possible to add something like $row['mysqlrow']; into the var_dump?

Comment: Yah you can do that. like $result['mysqlrow']="something"